# Angular Data Service across two cshtml pages

Tags: angularjs, service

I need to share data across controllers.  So I have my shared array returned from a service and then inject the service into any controllers that need to access it.

```
angular.module('mappingLayers', [])
    .constant('MODULE_VERSION', '0.0.3')
    .service('layersAvailableToMap', function () {
        return [];
    });
;
```

I'm also using the MVC4 template, and the RenderBody calls one of two different index.cshtml 
pages/views

_Layout.cshtml

```
<header>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="float-left">
            <p class="site-title">My Title</p>
        </div>
        <div class="float-right">
            <section id="login">
                Hello, <span >@User.Identity.Name</span>
                    </section>
                <nav>
                <ul id="menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Portfolio", "Index", "Home")</li>
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Index", "Profile")</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div data-ng-app="portfolioApp">
    <section >
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
</div>
```

The problem arises when I switch between index.cshtml pages (via Portfolio and Profile ActionLinks and rendered through RenderBody()) and **my shared data service array gets recreated** - i.e. one for each page.

**So, the question is, how do I share my service across controllers in different pages rendered via RenderBody from my _layout page.**

Injecting the service in multiple controllers within one of the pages works fine.

Incidentally, switching between the two index.cshtml pages (i.e. calling RenderBody) seems to cause a full page refresh/callback, when I don't think it should.  This might point towards the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Michael, you are not using the Angular Routing system correct? In other words, is this a SPA or a traditional Web Application?

Comment: I'm trying to create a SPA, which I thought the MVC 4 template gave me, but on second look, I think I thought wrong.  I am going to take the whole MVC ActionLink stuff out and just go with the angular routeprovider and ngView approach.

Comment: That would be my approach. Your array keeps getting reset because of the page load. Moving that to an angular SPA would remedy that. If however you decided to keep it as a traditional app and still use AngularJS, then you would want to look at using LocalStorage to hold your values even when the page refreshes. Hope this helps!